# javascript: array of object for simple localization

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, localization

I need to implement a simple way to handle localization about weekdays' names, and I came up with the following structure:

```
var weekdaysLegend=new Array(
{'it-it':'Lunedì', 'en-us':'Monday'}, 
{'it-it':'Martedì', 'en-us':'Tuesday'},
{'it-it':'Mercoledì', 'en-us':'Wednesday'},
{'it-it':'Giovedì', 'en-us':'Thursday'}, 
{'it-it':'Venerdì', 'en-us':'Friday'},
{'it-it':'Sabato', 'en-us':'Saturday'}, 
{'it-it':'Domenica', 'en-us':'Sunday'}
);
```

I know I could implement something like an associative array (given the fact that I know that javascript does not provide associative arrays but objects with similar structure), but i need to iterate through the array using numeric indexes instead of labels.
So, I would like to handle this in a for cycle with particular values (like j-1 or indexes like that).
Is my structure correct? Provided a variable "lang" as one of the value between "it-it" or "en-us", I tried to print weekdaysLegend[j-1][lang] (or weekdaysLegend[j-1].lang, I think I tried everything!) but the results is [object Object]. Obviously I'm missing something..
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure looks fine. You should be able to access values by:

`weekdaysLegend[0]["en-us"]; // returns Monday`

Of course this will also work for values in variables such as:

`weekdaysLegend[i][lang];`

```
for (var i = 0; i < weekdaysLegend.length; i++) {
    alert(weekdaysLegend[i]["en-us"]);
}
```

This will alert the days of the week.

Sounds like you're doing everything correctly and the structure works for me as well.

Comment: mmm, that's weird. If I alert the value as you suggest, it gave me the right value. But that's not happening in my cycle, the value remains [object Object].

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb. I forgot I had to change the way I recall my array TWICE in my library, so the wrong result is from this forgotten line.  Sorry for losing your time!

Comment: No problem! No time wasted. Glad you got it. :)

Comment: I recommend that you split out languages into seperate files for caching, as you will never need multiple languages at the same time. 

Check my answer to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small note (I see the answer is already marked) as I am currently designing on a large application where I want to put locals into a javascript array.

Assumption: 1000 words x4 languages generates 'xx-xx' + the word itself...

Thats 1000 rows pr. language + the same 7 chars used for language alone = wasted bandwitdh...

- the client/browser will have to PARSE THEM ALL before it can do any lookup in the arrays at all.

here is my approach:

**Why not generate the javascript for one language at a time, if the user selects another language, just respond(send) the right javascript to the browser to include?**

Either store a separate javascript with large array for each language OR use the language as parametre to the server-side script aka:

If the language file changes a lot or you need to minimize it per user/module, then its quite archivable with this approach as you can just add an extra parametre for "which part/module" to generate or a timestamp so the cache of the javascript file will work until changes occures.

if the dynamic approach is too performance heavy for the webserver, then publish/generate the files everytime there is a change/added a new locale - all you'll need is the "language linker" check in the top of the page, to check which language file to server the browser.

**Conclusion**

This approach will remove the overhead of a LOT of repeating "language" ID's if the locales list grows large.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access an index from the array, and then a value by specifying a key from the object.

This works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/98Sda/.

```
var day = 2;
var lang = 'en-us';

var weekdaysLegend = [
{'it-it':'Lunedì', 'en-us':'Monday'}, 
{'it-it':'Martedì', 'en-us':'Tuesday'},
{'it-it':'Mercoledì', 'en-us':'Wednesday'},
{'it-it':'Giovedì', 'en-us':'Thursday'}, 
{'it-it':'Venerdì', 'en-us':'Friday'},
{'it-it':'Sabato', 'en-us':'Saturday'}, 
{'it-it':'Domenica', 'en-us':'Sunday'}
];

alert(weekdaysLegend[day][lang]);
```